# How to display variables' value in Visual Studio like in Spyder

Tags: python, visual-studio, variables

I want to inspect the value of several Python variables. Normally I would use the `QuickWatch`, but when I'm dealing with a large matrix, I find a problem: I can't inspect the whole matrix.

It displays just like the `print()` function, simplified, like this:

```
array([[ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],       [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],       [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],       ...,        [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],       [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],       [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf]])
```

Yet **I want to inspect values on some certain positions**.I know in Spyder the variable explorer displays the whole value, so I wonder if there's a similar way to do this in Visual Studio.